# Dynamic scheme coloring based on info from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, bitmap, draw

I am developing an application for cemetery management in C# and SQL Server. It is my first "big" project, and I'm kinda lost now.

First, some info about the app:

- Has 3 local database files, one for authorizations (Login and permission purposes), another for option storing (each of these two has only one table) and another for the system itself (this is the main one, and has 5 tables).
- In general, the system stores all the info of a small cemetery. This info includes deceased, graves and payments (3 tables). The other 2 tables are one for crossed information and another for vacant graves.
- There's storing and retrieval of info between the C# GUI and the SQL.
- The application is for academic purposes.

**The problem:**
I thought it would be cool to implement a graphical scheme that visually shows the relation between graves with colors:

- **Green** for sold graves
- **Yellow** for graves on lease with good payment
- **Orange** for graves on lease in debt
- **Blue** for vacant graves (ones that can be sold)

An image that better explain what I have in mind:
[image]

This is a TabControl in a WinForm, and in one of the tabs it will receive the so called colored scheme. **The scheme is supposed to be blank at first, and then, based on database info about graves, it will be dynamically colored.**

And I have **no idea** how to do this, so I'm open for some ideas. I think I may have to mess around with some Bitmap methods or some Draw/Paint object.

Comment: You can lease a grave?

Comment: Yup, the graves originnally belong to a state institution, and some people buy them, others prefer a lease that is payed annually...but that's not the point, is it?...lol

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, I assume that the person leases the plot while they are still alive.

Comment: You can add a grid control inside that tab of the Tab Control.

Comment: Well, I can understand you curiosity, I know it doesn't make much sense, but this is a small town, and most people are still trustworthy, and normally the person who pays the lease is family related. GridView, ok..what about the dynamic coloring?..can it be done?

Comment: You will find some results using Google.      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red; allows you to change an individual cell colour.

Comment: Ah, that should be enough to keep me in the right path... Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Aedahl - not directly an answer to your question but you most likely don't want to use a different database to store each of your entities. You should use different tables in the same database.

Comment: thanks for pointing me that @MikeDinescu...will join all tables under one DB soon. Honestly, don't know why I created 3 DB...